# npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<html>

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npm-publish

I can see there are many questions asked here that are the same as mine.
But please have a look at my description.

After adding the user in NPM registry

```
npm adduser --registry="http://mylocalreg.com"
```

I am geeting error like

```
npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '<html>
npm ERR! <head><title...'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dk/.npm/_logs/2019-03-13T06_50_02_790Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Do you use any proxy servers?

Comment: Did you check the contents of `/home/dk/.npm/_logs/2019-03-13T06_50_02_790Z-debug.log`?

Comment: Thanks to all. Actually its mistake from our side. we were entered the wrong registry URL.